# TextView at the bottom of ListView - api 7

Tags: android, xml, listview

I'm trying to add a textview after a Listview (to the bottom of the Listview). **(API 7)**

For some reason it appears a the top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0c46a6"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/skypename"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="0dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"         
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="12pt"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />        

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using LinearLayout with orientation vertical and you have defined TextView before ListView. So first TextView will be drawn after that ListView.

Use `RelativeLayout` instead and use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for TextView to align at the bottom of the parent and `android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"` for list view to keep the listview to the top of textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0c46a6"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/skypename"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="0dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"         
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="12pt"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"/>        

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0c46a6"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/skypename"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"         
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="12pt"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom" />   

  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottom"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
                android:textSize="12pt"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I re-arranged my LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout but it wasn't as easy as I thought. In my case I had TextViews both above and below the ListView.

In order for the ListView to NOT cover either of the TextViews I had to use "layout_below" and "layout_above" in the layout that contains the ListView. Like this for the list-views layout:

```
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_layout"
```

When I wrote this from the bottom TextView:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/listview_layout"
```

the list covered it (=doesn't work).

So, the trick seems to be the placement of the layout_below and layout_above tags.

Another solution (that doesn't require a RelativeLayout) is to add a footer view to your list. Like this:

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container, false); 
    myItemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, com.example.app.R.layout.listitem, theList);
    View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notify_row, null);
    mListView.addFooterView(footer);  
    mListView.setAdapter(myItemAdapter);
    return v;
    }
```

For this solution you will have to create a layout file for your bottom view. Also you have to call addFooterView before you call setAdapter.

Answer (score -1):

If you provide properties as fillparent for height and width then you will never see the textview below listview.

You can do one thing: supply height as fixed dp and then place your textview below list.